# Adding a custom symbol/logo as a font character to XeteX/Latex

Tags: xetex, symbols, fontawesome

Imagine you have logo or pictogram you would like to use as a font in XeTeX/LateX much like the [fontawesome](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/fontawesome?lang=en) package provides for the likes of twitter, github etc. How would one go about this ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Your title says "XeLaTeX", but your body text says "LaTeX". And what does it mean to 'use a pictogram as a font in LaTeX'?

Comment: Instead of importing SVGs or PNG (which are unfortunately rasterized and don't scale well) into your document one can embed them as an icon in a font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get a not yet existing **symbol** as a character in LaTex from a logo or comparable, please follow these steps:

**Disclaimer: This is not a scientific approach nor one founded in Software Engineering. You can file it as a life hack if you so will.**

System used (YMMV):

- Windows 7.1 x64
- XeLatex
- MikTex 2.9
- fontspec package

### Step 1

Create an .svg file of your desired symbol using the tool of your choice. [InkScape][1] is a good [FOSS][2] program to do so. Alternatively, VectorMagic is an incredibly good suite for nearly 100% automation of vectorization and tracing.

Remember to save it as SVG 1.1. For this walkthrough, no further constraints are required.

### Step 2

Having done so, you can use a number of "font generators" on the web. I have tried a number of them ([fontello][3], [icomoon][4], [fontastic][5]), but only fontastic generated **correct** .ttf files that I could install and that actually contained the symbols I produced.

Going with fontastic you need to

- register
- log in

After logging in, click on [Add more icons][6] in the top navbar. Now you can click on the import button and select your .svg file for upload.

After that, you need to go back to 'Home' and then click on 'Select'.
Here you should click on the icon you just uploaded - it has already been 'fontified' . Great !

Select all other icons you might want in the font you are about to generate or simply repeat this step until all your icons have been fontified.

### Step 3

Now you click on 'Customize' in the middle navbar.

Now you can do two things:

1. change the **css class mapping** you would later use for the icons (mostly for web devs and web designers)
2. change the **character mapping** which you will need for this to work in XeteX

For instance, if your desired logo maps to the capital M, then typing M after selecting your font in LateX will result in your icon showing up !

After adjusting your mappings to your need, proceed to 'Publish'.

Here you want to download your font to install it manually on your system.

### Step 4

After downloading your font, you can install it (on Windows) by opening the zip, navigating to the 'fonts' fodler contained within and doubleclicking on the file with the **.ttf** extension. If you cannot see extensions on your system, either activate file extensions to show up or look for a file icon with a small, capital 'A'.

THe font preview window opens where you can check if your font has come out as expected. Click on the 'install' button to install this font on your system for use anywhere.

### Step 5

In order to use your font in your tex document, you can add a **class file** upon which your **.tex** will be based. Just make sure you create the classfile.cls in the same directory as your .tex.

Here is an example of my classfile fot the document class 'article:

```
\ProvidesClass{friggeri-cv}[2012/04/30 CV class]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\DeclareOption{print}{\def\@cv@print{}}
\DeclareOption*{%
  \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}%
}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{article}

%%%%%%%%%
% Fonts %
%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\customfont[]{generated-font-2}
```

The last two lines create a new command for you to use in your tex file: `\customfont{}`

### Step 6

Lastly, you need to add the classfile to the header of your tex file by putting

```
\documentclass[]{yourclassfile}
```

at its very beginning. You're now set to go! YOu can use {\customfont } to get your symbol in the right size and manipulate it like a font character!

I welcome all feedback to improve this post - feel free to comment.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just insert the picture file as a figure, or create the logo within LaTeX with TikZ?

Comment: Get a clock and demonstrate how your TikZing the [smarterer](http://www.smarterer.com) logo is faster than generating an svg, uploading it someplace, copying it to your font folder, including a few lines of code and tadaa, having it finished ?

Comment: I have a feeling you miss the use case for having small, scalable icons in tex. There are new brands created every single day. Using huge chunks of code whose flow is tough to control compared to font characters doesn't seem to be a good solution.

Comment: @Ledewde I have used that method as well but never thought of writing it up. nice one. The method I have used relied a bit less on online services but could be done entirely with inkscape and fontforge.

Comment: I couldnt get fontforge to compile on windows.

Comment: they seem to have a binary installer for windows these days. I am a unix user so I don't touch windows that much, but the website claim they have one.

Comment: Hi - Im totally new to latex, and got to step 6 but I don't understand how to customize the cls file. Should `generated-font-2` be the path to my tif file `~/.local/share/fonts`? What arguments go inside the ` {}` of the `customfont` command? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @tytire you need to properly install the font. This is dependent on the OS, I do not know enough about that with regard to Linux/Mac. After that the FONT NAME should be added as an argument to the customfont command.

Comment: @TytireRecubans customfont is to be used like any other font command.